# I am confused why I am getting so many error messages after trying to use split and adding a string to json output python

Tags: python

I am having trouble with this block of code. I am using OpenWeather API to get weather data, that is all good. But when this block executes, the first two lines of the current_temperature block of code works fine, but then when I try to split it, it returns an error. I also try to add the degree sign to the end, which returns an error.

With the current_pressure, I try to add the hPa suffix and that returns an error. Any ideas?? I really need this to work.

```py
import json, requests

current_temperature = y['temp']
current_temperature = (current_temperature - 273.15) * 9/5 + 32
current_temperature = current_temperature.split(5,-1)
current_temperature = current_temperature + '°'

current_pressure = y['pressure']
current_pressure = current_pressure + ' hPa'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Because `current_temperature` is a number, which you cannot split. You can split strings, for example, but not numbers.

Comment: I try to do str() but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: What do you want to do with split() exactly? I mean, what would you like `current_temperature` to have after its last modification?

Comment: What do you want `current_temperature.split(5,-1)` to return?

Comment: I would like it to get rid of everything after the hundredths place (that's why split is there) and give it the degree symbol. With the pressure, I only want to add the hPa suffix.

Comment: I think you wanted something like `current_temperature = str(current_temperature)[5:]`, but I still do not understand what you want to remove. Can you give us an example, please?

Comment: Ok, so let's say it starts at 50.7933000000000000001. I would like the split function to turn it into 50.79, and then add the ° to get 50.79°.

Comment: use python's math.round function or a truncator @Kizuo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is to first round (or truncate, but in the following example I round) the number, and then turn it into a string so you can format the output. You could do something like this:

```
current_temperature = y['temp']
current_temperature = (current_temperature - 273.15) * 9/5 + 32
current_temperature = round(current_temperature, 2)
current_temperature = f'{current_temperature}°'
```